# What is the best way to store data in an app, that will not be updated by the user?

Tags: java, android, database

I am making an activity where the user inputs their weight into an EditText field. Based on the value they write, a GridView with around 20 numeric values will be updated.

I already have all the numbers I need in an Excel file. The weight could be used as a key and the values can be Array of doubles that are returned for each key.

Can you give me an advice what's the best way to store this information for the app and to fetch it to the screen?

So far the options I have looked at are sqlite database and SharedPreferences, but maybe there's a better way? I don't want the user to be able delete these values by clearing data / cache, yet it doesn't seem like a good idea to hard-code them into the source code.

Comment: You can use Google Drive for storing specific appdata which is totally hidden from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they don't change, then hardcoding is exactly what you want. Even if you did put them in SharedPreferences or a DB, they need to come from somewhere.

To be neater, you could make your arrays as XML resources. Each item in a resource array can also reference a resource value. It'll be easier to change in updates if needed, but in the end, there won't be any functional difference from just making arrays in code.